# ejabberd Server uses Diffie-Hellman parameters of < 2048 bits. Grade capped to B

Tags: ubuntu, xmpp

Использовала версию ejabberd 2, но при анализе сервера получала класс не выше С, обновила до 15, где можно отключить использование ssl3 в итоге в отчете пропало большинство сообщений о плохой настройке, а класс сервера стал B. Осталось одно сообщение которое мешает перейти на класс А - Server uses Diffie-Hellman parameters of < 2048 bits. Grade capped to B. Кто-нибудь сталкивался как это исправить?

Comment: Походу у тебя хреново сгенеренный или сертификат или чё-то открыто-закрытое. 2048 - очень похоже. Попробуй это самое хз что переделать на 4096.

Comment: Кстати, не оно? https://serverfault.com/q/731394/315697

Comment: Привет. Должно помочь вот это решение: https://forum.vovit.ru/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=32251#p54368 Пробовал настроить как писали здесь https://serverfault.com/q/731394/315697, но в итоге у меня сервер едва запустился и подключиться к нему нельзя было.